# Internet Explorer/Safari Flexbox(?) and Alignment Issues

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, flexbox

I'm having some issues with item alignment in IE and Safari and I'm not that good on cross-browser compatibility so would appreciate it if someone could suggest what I'm doing wrong with the following or what may be a good general fix.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/nickwcook/pen/vxjavM?editors=0110.

EDIT: Home image alignment sorted, but still having issues with the following:

The text in the About section of the page is fine in other browsers, but in IE its not taking into account the horizontal padding (30px) of the parent, and is actually overflowing past the sides of the viewport.

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="portfolioApp" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar">

    <div id="borderTop"></div>

     <div id="borderRight"></div>

    <div id="borderBottom"></div>

    <div id="borderLeft"></div>

    <div id="logo">

        <a href="#"></a>

        <img src="img/logo-basic-dark.png" alt="Logo">

     </div>

     <div class="container-fluid">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

            <div class="navbar-header">

                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">

                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        

                </button>

            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">

                    <li class="navLink"><a href="#home" alt="Home Button">Home</a></li>

                    <li class="navLink"><a href="#about" alt="About Button">About</a></li>

                    <li class="navLink"><a href="#work" alt="Work Button">Work</a></li>

                    <li class="navLink"><a href="#contact" alt="Contact Button">Contact</a></li>

                </ul>

            </div>

        </nav>

    </div>

    <main>

        <section id="home">

            <div class="sectionContent">

                <div id="homeText">

                    <h1 id="homePrimary">Home Text Primary</h1>

                    <h2 id="homeSecondary">Home Text Secondary</h2>

                </div>

                <div id="homeImageContainer">

                    <div id="homeImage" class="blend-red-blue">

                        <div id="homeImageMask"></div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </section>

        <section id="about" ng-controller="skillsController">

            <div class="sectionContent">

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-push-2">

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                        <div id="skillsList">

                           <p>My skills include:</p>

                            <p ng-repeat="skill in skills" class="skillItem">{{skill.name}}</p>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </section>

        <section id="work" ng-controller="projectsController">

            <div class="sectionContent">

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="project col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">

                        <div>

                            <h2>Project One</h2>

                            <h4>Project Description</h4>

                            <a ng-href="#" target="blank_">View Project</a>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                  <div class="project col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">

                        <div>

                            <h2>Project One</h2>

                            <h4>Project Description</h4>

                            <a ng-href="#" target="blank_">View Project</a>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                  <div class="project col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">

                        <div>

                            <h2>Project One</h2>

                            <h4>Project Description</h4>

                            <a ng-href="#" target="blank_">View Project</a>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                  <div class="project col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">

                        <div>

                            <h2>Project One</h2>

                            <h4>Project Description</h4>

                            <a ng-href="#" target="blank_">View Project</a>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </section>

        <section id="contact">

            <div class="sectionContent">



            </div>

        </section>

    </main>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
/* GENERAL LAYOUT */

html, body 
{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
background-color: #fefefe;
overflow-x: hidden;
}

/* SECTIONS */

section
{
display: block;
margin: 0;
background: transparent;
z-index: 90;
}

.sectionContent
{
min-height: 100vh;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
padding: 100px 30px;
box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* HOME SECTION */

#home #homeImageContainer
{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

#home #homeImage
{
position: absolute;
height: 30vw;
width: 30vw;
background-image: url('../img/laptop-hands.png');
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
z-index: 90;
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 100px 4px rgba(153,153,153,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 100px 4px rgba(153,153,153,1);
box-shadow: 3px 3px 100px 4px rgba(153,153,153,1);
}

#home #homeImage > #homeImageMask
{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: rgba(84, 17, 200, 0.6);
z-index: 91;
}

#home #homeText
{
z-index: 95;
}

#homeText h1#homePrimary,
#homeText h2#homeSecondary
{
color: #000;
text-align: center;
}

#homeText h1#homePrimary
{
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: 600;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#homeText h2#homeSecondary
{
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 600;
}


/* ABOUT SECTION */

#about p
{
line-height: 26px;
text-align: center;
}

#about #skillsList
{
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 50px;
}

#about #skillsList p:first-of-type
{
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#about #skillsList p.skillItem
{
display: inline;
margin: 0 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what about simplifying like this:

```css
body, h1, h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.box-content {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 100px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgba(84, 17, 200, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 100px 4px rgba(153, 153, 153, 1);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="sectionContent">
  <div id="homeText" class="box-content">
    <h1 id="homePrimary">Home Text Primary</h1>
    <h2 id="homeSecondary">Home Text Secondary</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sectionContent is not meant to be height/width 30vw. This is adding properties to the wrong container. Take a look at the HTML structure in codepen

Comment: I've updated the answer to use another class `box-content` without affecting `.sectionContent` below

Comment: I've solved the first issue since then. It's just the second I'm still having trouble with

Answer (score 0):

You can remove absolute css property from selector '#home #homeImage' issue is fixed at my end